# Use custom TablecellRenderer in a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I am new to Java. I have created a `JTable`. This is how `addRow` method works when I  try to add a row to the table.

```
private void addTableRow(String type, String name, String rank, String notes, String location, Color color)
    {
        boolean isExport = isExportEnable();

        tableModel.addRow(new Object[]
        {
            type,
            name,
            rank,
            notes,
            location,
            isExport
        });
    }
```

When adding the row I want to fill a different color for the column index 6. I created a custom table cell renderer.

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int col) 
{
    getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, col);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    return this;
}
```

But I have no idea:

1. How should I call this method when adding a row? I tried to call it after `isExport` value but there, it shows errors for method parameters.
2. What values should I use for parameters in `getTableCellRendererComponent()` method?

Comment: You're not supposed to call that method, ever. The JTable calls it every time it needs to render a cell. The first instruction should be **super.**getTable...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JTable Cell Renderer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644922/jtable-cell-renderer)